# L'Hospital rule to find limit on indeterminate form.

Tags: limits, derivatives, substitution

I have the following limit to compute:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\cos x -1\over {5 x^2}\right)}$$
I need to find the limit as $x \to 0$.  I tried using L'Hospital rule , so I found the derivative of the numerator, which is:
$${-\sin x}$$
The derivative of the denominator is: $${10x}$$

Now I have the following:

$${-\sin x \over {10x}}$$

What should I do now? , I'm not sure on how I could apply direct substitution to this problem?

Comment: apply l-hospitals rule agian!

Comment: in what sense do you mean?

Comment: I think what is meant is that sometimes applying l'Hospital's rule results again in an indeterminate form.  Your problem requires applying the rule once again to the result you got.  Twice should be enough (in this case)!

Comment: If im understanding correctly should i just find the derivate of the already found ones?

Comment: Right.  Do the same thing here $\cdots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply L'Hospital's rule again:
$$\lim_{x→0}\frac{(-\sin x)'}{(10x)'}$$
$$= \lim_{x→0}\frac{-\cos(x)}{10}$$
$$= \frac{-\cos(0)}{10}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me point that the limit as $x\to 0$ of $\:\dfrac{\sin x}x\:$ is a basic high-school result. Therefore, you can write
$$\frac{-\sin x}{10 x}=-\frac1{10}\underbrace{\frac{\sin x}x}_{\substack{\downarrow\\1}}.$$